# Flutter icon not changing in iOS "recents" view

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, icons, launcher

I have an app in Flutter that I just built for iOS.
I have replaced the icons in `AppIcon.appiconset` and it seems to have reflected in the Home Screen, but in the “recent apps” screen it still shows the flutter logo.

Here's the home screen:

[image]

and here's the recents screen:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Comment: have you reinstalled the application after changing the logo?

Comment: Yes, I did reinstall the app.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue simply by removing the app, then restarting the emulator, and installing the app again.

For some reason just reinstalling the app didn't help, it needed a restart between installs.